# subset NumericMatrix by row and column names in Rcpp

Tags: rcpp

I am trying to create a function in Rcpp that will take as input a pairwise numeric matrix, as well as a list of vectors, each element being a subset of row/column names. I would like this function identify the subset of the matrix that matches those names, and return the mean of the values.

Below I generated some dummy data that resembles the sort of data I have, and follow with an attempt of a Rcpp function.

```
library(Rcpp)

dat <- c(spA = 4, spB = 10, spC = 8, spD = 1, spE = 5, spF = 9)
pdist <- as.matrix(dist(dat))
pdist[upper.tri(pdist, diag = TRUE)] <- NA
```

Here I have a list made up of character vectors of various subsets of the row/column names in pdist

```
subsetList <- replicate(10, sample(names(dat), 4), simplify=FALSE)
```

For each of these sets of names, I would like to identify the subset of the pairwise matrix and take the mean of the values

Here is what I have so far, which does not work, but I think it illustrates where I am trying to get.

```
cppFunction('
    List meanDistByCell(List input, NumericMatrix pairmat) {
    int n = input.size();
    List out(n);

    List dimnames = pairmat.attr( "dimnames" );
    CharacterVector colnames = dimnames[1];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        CharacterVector sp = as< CharacterVector >(input[i]);

        if (sp.size() > 0) {
            out[i] = double(mean(pairmat(sp, sp)));
        } else {
            out[i] = NA_REAL;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: There is no support for this feature presently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although (contiguous) range-based subsetting is available (e.g. `x(Range(first_row, last_row), Range(first_col, last_col))`), as coatless pointed out, subsetting by `CharacterVector` is not currently supported, so you will have to roll your own for the time being. A general-ish approach might look something like this:

```cpp
template <int RTYPE> inline Matrix<RTYPE>
Subset2D(const Matrix<RTYPE>& x, CharacterVector crows, CharacterVector ccols) {
    R_xlen_t i = 0, j = 0, rr = crows.length(), rc = ccols.length(), pos;
    Matrix<RTYPE> res(rr, rc);

    CharacterVector xrows = rownames(x), xcols = colnames(x);
    IntegerVector rows = match(crows, xrows), cols = match(ccols, xcols);

    for (; j < rc; j++) {
        // NB: match returns 1-based indices
        pos = cols[j] - 1;
        for (i = 0; i < rr; i++) {
            res(i, j) = x(rows[i] - 1, pos);
        }
    }

    rownames(res) = crows;
    colnames(res) = ccols;

    return res;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix subset2d(NumericMatrix x, CharacterVector rows, CharacterVector cols) {
    return Subset2D(x, rows, cols);
}
```

This assumes that the input matrix has both row and column names, and that the row and column lookup vectors are valid subsets of those dimnames; additional defensive code could be added to make this more robust. To demonstrate,

```
subset2d(pdist, subsetList[[1]], subsetList[[1]])
#     spB spD spE spC
# spB  NA  NA  NA  NA
# spD   9  NA  NA   7
# spE   5   4  NA   3
# spC   2  NA  NA  NA

pdist[subsetList[[1]], subsetList[[1]]]
#     spB spD spE spC
# spB  NA  NA  NA  NA
# spD   9  NA  NA   7
# spE   5   4  NA   3
# spC   2  NA  NA  NA
```

---

`Subset2D` takes care of most of the boilerplate involved in implementing `meanDistByCell`; all that remains is to loop over the input list, apply this to each list element, and store the mean of the result in the output list:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List meanDistByCell(List keys, NumericMatrix x, bool na_rm = false) {
    R_xlen_t i = 0, sz = keys.size();
    List res(sz);

    if (!na_rm) {
        for (; i < sz; i++) {
            res[i] = NumericVector::create(
                mean(Subset2D(x, keys[i], keys[i]))
            );
        }
    } else {
        for (; i < sz; i++) {
            res[i] = NumericVector::create(
                mean(na_omit(Subset2D(x, keys[i], keys[i])))
            );
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

```r
all.equal(
    lapply(subsetList, function(x) mean(pdist[x, x], na.rm = TRUE)),
    meanDistByCell2(subsetList, pdist, TRUE)
)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

Although the use of `Subset2D` allows for a much cleaner implementation of `meanDistByCell`, in this situation it is inefficient for at least a couple of reasons:

- It sets the dimnames of the return object (`rownames(res) = crows;`, `colnames(res) = ccols;`), which you have no need for here.
- It makes a call to `match` to obtain indices for *each* of `rownames` and `colnames`, which is unnecessary since you know in advance that `rownames(x) == colnames(x)`.

You will incur the cost of both of these points `k` times, for an input list with length `k`.

A more efficient -- but consequently less concise -- approach would be to essentially implement only the aspects of `Subset2D` that are needed, inline inside of `meanDistByCell`:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List meanDistByCell2(List keys, NumericMatrix x, bool na_rm = false) {
    R_xlen_t k = 0, sz = keys.size(), i = 0, j = 0, nidx, pos;
    List res(sz);
    CharacterVector cx = colnames(x);

    if (!na_rm) {
        for (; k < sz; k++) {
            // NB: match returns 1-based indices
            IntegerVector idx = match(as<CharacterVector>(keys[k]), cx) - 1;
            nidx = idx.size();
            NumericVector tmp(nidx * nidx);

            for (j = 0; j < nidx; j++) {
                pos = idx[j];
                for (i = 0; i < nidx; i++) {
                    tmp[nidx * j + i] = x(idx[i], pos);
                }
            }

            res[k] = NumericVector::create(mean(tmp));
        }
    } else {
        for (; k < sz; k++) {
            IntegerVector idx = match(as<CharacterVector>(keys[k]), cx) - 1;
            nidx = idx.size();
            NumericVector tmp(nidx * nidx);

            for (j = 0; j < nidx; j++) {
                pos = idx[j];
                for (i = 0; i < nidx; i++) {
                    tmp[nidx * j + i] = x(idx[i], pos);
                }
            }

            res[k] = NumericVector::create(mean(na_omit(tmp)));
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

```r
all.equal(
    meanDistByCell(subsetList, pdist, TRUE),
    meanDistByCell2(subsetList, pdist, TRUE)
)
# [1] TRUE
```

---